# Watch a specific attribute of each and every object in an object array - Angular material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I want to listen to a specific attribute of each and every object of an object array and change another attribute value in the object according to the changing attribute. I am using Angular material's md-select to change the attribute value. So far I have tried as below. But it is not working. Where have I gone wrong? Please help.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module( 'app', ['ngAria', 'ngAnimate','ngMaterial']);

app.controller('appController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.modes = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];

    $scope.items = [
  {id: "1", text: "word", textMode: {id: 1}},
  {id: "2", text: "word", textMode: {id: 1}},
  {id: "3", text: "word", textMode: {id: 1}}
  ];

  angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
    $scope.$watch('item.textMode.id', function () {
        if (item.textMode.id === 1) {
        item.text = "word";
      } else if (item.textMode.id === 2) {
        item.text = "phrase";
      } else if (item.textMode.id === 3) {
        item.text = "paragraph";
      }
    })
  });
});
```

index.html

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="appController">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <md-select aria-label="textChanger" class="selector" ng-model="item.textMode.id" placeholder="Text mode ID">
        <md-option ng-repeat="mode in modes" ng-value="mode.id">
          {{mode.id}}
        </md-option>
      </md-select>

      <br>
      {{item.text}}

      <br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lpsandaruwan/ho5egr16/](https://jsfiddle.net/lpsandaruwan/ho5egr16/)

Comment: don't have angular.js experiance, but your function is not triggered when the drop-down value changes

Comment: Look into using $watchCollection instead of $watch. Also I think you should simplify your items object, some of the properties seem redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have solved my problem. Instead of watching the specific attribute, I chose the `ng-change`. It simply has the ability to change the appropriate attribute.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module( 'app', ['ngAria', 'ngAnimate','ngMaterial']);

app.controller('appController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.modes = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];

    $scope.items = [
  {id: "1", text: "word", textMode: {id: 1}},
  {id: "2", text: "word", textMode: {id: 1}},
  {id: "3", text: "word", textMode: {id: 1}}
  ];

  $scope.onChange = function(item) {
    if (item.textMode.id === 1) {
        item.text = "word";
      } else if (item.textMode.id === 2) {
        item.text = "phrase";
      } else if (item.textMode.id === 3) {
        item.text = "paragraph";
      }
  };
});
```

index.html

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="appController">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <md-select aria-label="textChanger" class="selector" ng-model="item.textMode.id" ng-change="onChange(item)" placeholder="Text mode ID">
        <md-option ng-repeat="mode in modes" ng-value="mode.id">
          {{mode.id}}
        </md-option>
      </md-select>

      <br>
      {{item.text}}

      <br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/lpsandaruwan/ho5egr16/6/](https://jsfiddle.net/lpsandaruwan/ho5egr16/6/)

Comment: But of course, "kiss".  It's easy to get caught up in the power of a framework and lose sight of the straight forward things.  Don't forget to mark yours as the "accepted" response.

Answer (score 1):

Try this JavaScript/AngularJS controller tweak:

```
  $scope.$watch('items', function(newValues, oldValues) {
    for (var i = 0; i < newValues.length; i++) {
      if (newValues[i].textMode.id === 1) {
        newValues[i].text = "word";
      } else if (newValues[i].textMode.id === 2) {
        newValues[i].text = "phrase";
      } else if (newValues[i].textMode.id === 3) {
        newValues[i].text = "paragraph";
      }
    }
  }, true);
```

The trick is watching the array of objects for a property change (deep watch) with the 'true' in $watch.

Here's your JSFiddle updated, https://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/vndf0hcu/.

Comment: Thanks. :-) This does what I expected. But rather than running a loop every time I changed the value, is there a way to just change the required attribute of the appropriate object?

Comment: Not the way $watch works.  You did ask for a way to...  "listen to a specific attribute of each and every object of an object array and change another attribute value in the object according to the changing attribute."  So that is what I did... :-).